# JavaScript complains about a function I have defined

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I'm trying to write a simple object that calls a few member functions.

Surprisingly, JavaScript complains about a function called `uninstallLocalHost`.

```
Error: uninstallLocalHost is not defined
Source File: chrome://custombutton/content/button.js
Line: 39
```

Yet, it looks like this function *is* defined.
What could I be doing wrong?

```
var katimbaClass=
{       
    installLocalHost:function()
    {
        alert("localhost installed");
    },

    uninstallLocalHost:function()
    {
        alert("localhost uninstalled");
    },

    toggleInstall:function()
    {
        if(bInstalled) uninstallLocalHost();
         else installLocalHost();
    },

    bInstalled: false
};
```

When I attempt to call a function of `katimbaClass` elsewhere like so:

```
oncommand="katimbaClass.toggleInstall()"
```

I don't understand why the following error results:

```
Error: uninstallLocalHost is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` is not implicit. You must change these lines:

```
if(bInstalled) uninstallLocalHost();
else installLocalHost();
```

To these:

```
if(this.bInstalled) this.uninstallLocalHost();
else this.installLocalHost();
```

...or, alternatively, these:

```
if(katimbaClass.bInstalled) katimbaClass.uninstallLocalHost();
else katimbaClass.installLocalHost();
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is really strange that "this" is not explicit

Comment: @Dr Deo: You mean not implicit? It is explicit.

Comment: Javascript can seem like a 'strange' language sometimes :-) Also, please search Google for 'Javascript scoping and this'.

Answer (score 2):

Does this makes it simpler ?

```
var katimbaClass = new function() {
    this.installLocalHost= function () {
        alert("localhost installed");    
    };
    this.uninstallLocalHost= function () {
        alert("localhost UnInstalled");    
    };
    // ETC ..

}


oncommand="katimbaClass.toggleInstall()"
```